# Interstitial iAd delayed after pressing button

Tags: swift, delay, iad, interstitial

I'm trying to setup iAd after clicking cancel button on JSSAlert. I have in JSSAlert function that set alpha for full view 0.7.. And in view controller I have function for iAd and set back alpha to 1.0...

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = "Vyhodnotenie testu"
        self.showAlert()

    }


    func showAlert() {
        func callback(){}
        if numberOfPoints > 49 {
            let customIcon = UIImage(named: "smile")
            let alertview = JSSAlertView().show(self, title: "Gratulujeme! Uspeli ste.", text: "Dokončili ste test s počtom bodov \(numberOfPoints + 1) z \(maximumNumberOfPoints)!", buttonText: "OK!", color: UIColorFromHex(0x22c411, alpha: 1), iconImage: customIcon)
            alertview.setTextTheme(.Light)
            alertview.addAction(myCancelCallback)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.7
        } else {
            let customIcon = UIImage(named: "sad")
            let alertview = JSSAlertView().show(self, title: "Ľutujeme! Neuspeli ste.", text: "Dokončili ste test s počtom bodov \(numberOfPoints + 1) z \(maximumNumberOfPoints)!", buttonText: "OK!", color: UIColorFromHex(0xd20606, alpha: 1), iconImage: customIcon)
            alertview.addAction(myCancelCallback)
            alertview.setTextTheme(.Light)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.7
        }

    }

    func myCancelCallback() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic
    }


    func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

    }

    func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        interstitialAdView = UIView()
        interstitialAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
        view.addSubview(interstitialAdView)

        interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    }

    func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(var interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        interstitialAd = nil
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

    }

    func interstitialAdDidUnload(var interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        interstitialAd = nil
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Alpha back to 1.0 in function **myCancelCallback** is working but iAd is delayed.. What can cause that delay? Or how can I deal with it?

**I want to show iAd immediately after pressing OK!.**

Video how it's working:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6LKN-cjaz8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You are using `ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic` method which goes and request the ad if its available and then show it so the process takes time.

Comment: whats better to use?

Comment: please check my answer , i gave you two methods to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

> iAd App Network Shutdown As of December 31, 2016, the iAd App Network
> is no longer available. If you'd like to promote your apps, you can
> advertise using Search Ads, Apple News, or third party networks and
> advertising sellers.
>
> Reference: https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/

Here is what your gonna do, you have to create the interstitial including close button programmatically , i just made you a sample :

Add row in info.plist : `View controller-based status bar appearance` -> `NO`

in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method add the following line to insure that status bar will be not hidden :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.None)
```

Here is a full sample view controller of how your gonna add the interstitial programmatically , but you only need to write animation when the interstitial is showing instead of just using addSubView. you can use animate transform translation you will find a lot of samples about that.

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {
    
    
    var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!
    var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()
    var closeButton:UIButton!
    
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "loadInterstitialAd", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    

    
    func loadInterstitialAd() {
        interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()
        interstitialAd.delegate = self
    }
    
    func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("interstitialAdWillLoad")
    }
    
    func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)

        print("interstitialAdDidLoad")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
        interstitialAdView = UIView()
        interstitialAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(interstitialAdView)
        
        closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y:  15, width: 20, height: 20))
        //add a cross shaped graphics into your project to use as close button
        closeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "close"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("close"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(closeButton)
        
        interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    }
    
    func close() {
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
        closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
        interstitialAd = nil
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)

        
    }
    
    func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("interstitialAdActionDidFinish")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
    }

    
    func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("didFailWithError")
    }
    
    func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("interstitialAdDidUnload")
        close()
    }

    
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

}
```

**Update:** It might be you just have to call : `UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()` in `viewDidLoad` of your class to download the content of the interstitial so whenever you ask to present it will be ready and then might be no delay.